# R not able to locate gsl/gsl_rng.h

Tags: r, windows, gsl

I have to install the "cobreak" package in R (Windows 10), which is requiring the packages "rcpp" and "rcpparmadillo" as well as gsl. I installed GSL 2.6 via "cygwin" and tried again via "mingw". Still R cannot locate gsl when installing cobreak:

```
> *** arch - i386 /mingw32/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/Users/sakei/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/Rcpp/include' -I'C:/Users/sakei/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/RcppArmadillo/include'        -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign -c cointmdl.cc -o cointmdl.o In file included from genmdl.h:5,
>                  from cointmdl.cc:1: random_arma.h:4:10: fatal error: gsl/gsl_rng.h: No such file or directory  #include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
>           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I am having the same problem when I try to install `cobreak` package. This package is available as a source and depends on `BH` package previously knows as `boost` and also depends on `gsl` package. I have looked into some solution like the one on this link ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64373213/r-not-able-to-locate-gsl-gsl-rng-h) but it does not work on Windows machine